# Is there a nuance in meaning between 'non-managed' and 'unmanaged'?

Tags: word-usage, prefixes, nuance

Context: I am writing about 'devices not managed by professionals' and debating the subtleties between non-managed devices vs. unmanaged devices

Comment: Any distinction would be due to the specific jargon for the type of thing you're discussing.

Comment: Personal opinion here: non-managed devices don't need to be managed. Unmanaged devices are not managed, but maybe not because they don't need to be.

Comment: *Non-managed* is closer in meaning to *not managed* than is *unmanaged*. E.g. *unmanaged* can be used with the specific meaning *no longer managed*, but *non-managed* cannot. Also, *non-managed by A*, though a bit unusual, can be used to express just *not managed by A*, whereas *unmanaged by A* connotes some action or decision by A towards not managing.

Comment: The overlap in meaning is so significant that there would be no conclusive distinction apart from contextual clarification from the author, but in connection to @tkendrick20's comment, *unmanaged* might be more suitable for connoting a level of negligence.